# Adding image as BLOB in HSQLDB but something like ":hsqll:jdbc:client@f3t5h" ends up in the table

Tags: java, jdbc, blob, hsqldb

I am trying to add an Image as BLOB in HSQLDB. But in the table I find something like ":hsqll:jdbc:client@f3t5h". Is anything wrong with my Java code below?

My retrieving code is like this that i usually do for other databases. Why doesn't it work for HSQLDB?

```
   Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

   ResultSet results =stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from productdetails");


     while (results.next()) {
                String code = (String) results.getObject(1);
                String name = (String) results.getObjeenter code herect(2);

                String price = Double.toString((Double) results.getObject(3));
                int quantity = (Integer) results.getObject(4);
                Boolean featured = (Boolean) results.getObject(5);
                String desc = (String) results.getObject(6);
                String imgPath = (String) results.getObject(7);
                Blob aBlob = (Blob) results.getBlob(10);
                byte[] allBytesInBlob = aBlob.getBytes(1, (int) aBlob.length());

                try {
                    FileOutputStream fis =
              (FileOutputStream) getOutputStream(allBytesInBlob);

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Helper.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
}

public OutputStream getOutputStream(byte[] _data) throws IOException 
               {
            OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            out.write(_data);
             return out;
               }
```

That's my inserting code.

```
 Connection conn = db.getConnection();
 PreparedStatement pstmt;
 String sql = "INSERT INTO PRODUCTDETAILS"
( PRODUCTCODE, NAME, PRICE, QUANTITY, FEATURED, DESCRPTION,   IMAGEPATH,IMAGE )
               VALUES ( ?, ?,? ,? ,? , ?, ?,?)";
 pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        FileInputStream fis;


        File image = new File(values.getImgPath());
        fis = new FileInputStream(image);
        pstmt.setBinaryStream(8, (InputStream) fis, (int) (image.length()));
        pstmt.execute();
```

The `image` column is of type `BLOB`, obviously.

Comment: Why don't you add only image location rather than image to the database?

Comment: while retriving blob i am getting following error:             Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCBlobClient cannot be cast to com.mysql.jdbc.Blob

Comment: I see that you driver are different org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCBlobClient and com.mysql.jdbc.Blob which are different. See you connection parameter. So that you use driver for same hsql db.

Comment: Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"); i think there is no other way than this for getting driver, let met tell that i am using the "Stand alone" settings of hsqldb should i try some other settings ....?

Comment: I mean I am not using mysql driver anywhere in the code even the mysql connector does not exsist in d porject, so is the java code that i posted is just for mysql ,and is it creating blobs in mysql's form?

Comment: String imgPath = (String) results.getObject(7); Which is 7th column and Blob aBlob = (Blob) results.getBlob(10) is 10th the code you initally posted had blob object after imagepath I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Java code is correct for HSQLDB 2.2.x. The blob seems to be inserted. It seems the code your are using to retrieve the blob is incorrect. You have not reported this code, but obviously you are not using the java.sql.Blob methods to access the returned blob (the org.hsqldb.jdbcJDBCBLOBClient object). Post retrieve code for correction.

If you look at the table data in HSQLDB DatabaseManager or some other tools, it may show the blob as the address of the object, instead of showing the binary contents.

Answer (score 1):

You call `aBlob.getBytes(10, aBlob.length())`.

However, the first argument of [`Blob.getBytes()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html#getBytes%28long,%20int%29) is the index of the *first byte to retrieve* (1-based, as all indices in JDBC are). So you're *ignoring* (i.e. not fetching) the first 9 bytes of the `Blob`. Pass in `1` instead.

If the output is actually as you showed, then something else is wrong as well (probably the way you insert the `Blob`), but that's certainly the first problem you should fix.

Comment: i corrected that but there is no change..is there any useful link or tutorial to find out how actually Blobs are handled in HSqldb...? Specially inserting and retriving...

Comment: @NavinRajPandey: I'm not aware of requiring anything special for handling BLOBs in HSQLDB, it's pretty JDBC compliant in this. Since you've fixed your broken retrieval code, maybe it's time to show us *how you store* the BLOB in the first place.

Comment: @NavinRaj Please add both insert and retrieve code and add the SELECT statement used for retrieve.

Comment: @Jaochim Blob#getBytes(int pos, int length) counts pos from 1 not zero

Comment: @NavinRaj At the moment it is only the insert code. When you edit, include two blocks of code, one for insert, another for retrieve, including the SELECT statement.

Comment: @fredt: oops, of course. Curse JDBC for being the only Java API that has the notion of indices starting at 1.

Comment: @NavinRaj, Where is the SELECT statement? You should also apply Joachim's correction.

Answer (score 1):

Joachim: 10 is column index, not byte[index].

What you get is standard Object.toString().
„the image column is of type BLOB, obviously.”.  Yeah, in db. How about your table?
Is your model return generic String.class for this column? If so, you shoul check the object itself,
your data is inside (and object don't care if it's your mother in low picture or text).
Nice cast for byteoutputstream to fileoutputstream, in my java did not work